# How to set or specify privacy when POSTing any content to Facebook using Graph API for android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already refer [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563538/specify-privacy-when-posting-to-facebook-graph-api) and  [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395868/facebook-graph-api-how-to-set-the-privacy-settings) ,its very old post .

please go through it first , I already set privacy as per the post1 , like this

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", Message);
    JSONObject privacy = new JSONObject();
    try {
        switch (Level){
            case 0: 
                privacy.put("value", "SELF"); //for only me
                break;
            case 1: 
                privacy.put("value", "ALL_FRIENDS"); // for all friends
                break;
            case 2: 
                privacy.put("value", "EVERYONE");  //for public
                break;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
    }
    params.putString("privacy", privacy.toString());
```

Its working fine in case of **"SELF"** and **"ALL_FRIENDS"** privacy options **BUT** when I set it with **"EVERYONE"**  ,it will post for all-friend which is same as if we set privacy using  "ALL_FRIENDS" . I want to set privacy of fb post to #public , which means **"EVERYONE"** is not working as mention in docs. any reference link or any kind of help will applicate.Thanks .

Comment: you can´t set it to a broader audience than the one you selected when you authorized the app. afaik you can read about that in the docs.

Comment: may be I missed that thing ,can you plz text that portion of related docs @Iuschn ?apart from this we can set #self and #all-friend options like this ,then what is wrong with #Everyone  !

Comment: i will try to find it, but it´s 100% like that. isn´t it obvious too? there is a privacy setting when you authorize the app, you can´t set any broader audience for safety. that´s a fact.

Answer (score 0):

About the privacy field:

> This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the
>   one granted.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed#publish